# bipartite graph matching to match two sets

Tags: r, graph-theory, igraph

I'm a newbie to `igraph` package in R. I have two sets `A` and `B`, each with `N` vertices `(A1, A2, ..., AN)` and `(B1, B2, ..., BN)`. There is an edge between every element of `A` to every element of `B`, and I have a function `fWgt(Ai, Bj)` that returns the weights of the edge between `Ai` and `Bj`.

I have been trying to use the `igraph` package in R to do a weighted maximum bipartite matching, but I haven't been able to formulate the problem as per the `igraph` package. For instance, in the example given for `maximum.bipartite.matching` function in the `igraph` package:

```
Usage: 

maximum.bipartite.matching(graph, types = NULL, weights = NULL,
   eps = .Machine$double.eps) 

Example: 

g2 <- graph.formula( a-b-c-d-e-f-g )
V(g2)$type <- rep(c(FALSE,TRUE), length=vcount(g2))
str(g2, v=TRUE)
maximum.bipartite.matching(g2)
```

I couldn't figure out how to reformulate my problem (sets `A`, `B`, edges by `fWgt` function) using `graph.formula`? The `str` function in the example appears to set the edges, but what would be the equivalent of the `str` function for my case?

*** EDIT ***

Thanks for both your replies. I can only select one on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the `maximum.bipartite.matching` function in the `igraph` package, but you can solve this as an assignment problem with the `lp.assign` function in the `lpSolve` package:

```
library(lpSolve)
set.seed(144)
# For example, generate random weights
fWgt <- function(Ai, Bj) runif(1)
N <- 10
wts <- sapply(1:N, function(col) sapply(1:N, function(row) fWgt(row, col)))
res <- lp.assign(wts, "max")
res$solution
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#  [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0
#  [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0     0
#  [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1
#  [4,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
#  [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     0
#  [6,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#  [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0     0
#  [8,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#  [9,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [10,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0     0
res$objval
# [1] 8.557704
```

In this solution, the node 1 from `A` is assigned to node 8 from `B`, node 2 from `A` is assigned to node 7 from `B`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The `igraph` package comes with a nice built-in function `graph.full.bipartite` which you could use to create your bipartite graph, instead of `graph.formula`. Note that `str` is not *setting* the edges, it is a way to *inspect* that the graph you create is indeed what you wanted.

Once you have created the bipartite graph and set the edge weights, it is just a one line to get the maximal matching.

Here's an example with N=5. (Total of 10 vertices, 5 on each side.)

```
#create the graph
N <- 5
g3 <- graph.full.bipartite (N,N)
#Name the vertices A1...AN and B1..BN
V(g3)$name <- c(paste0("A", 1:N), paste0("B", 1:N))
#set the edge weights
set.seed(122)
E(g3)$weight <- sample(10,N^2, replace=T) #use your fWgt function here instead

#verifty if we did things right
str(g3, TRUE)
is.bipartite(g3)

maximum.bipartite.matching(g3)
#$matching_size
#[1] 5
#
#$matching_weight
#[1] 37
# 
#$matching
#  A1   A2   A3   A4   A5   B1   B2   B3   B4   B5 
#"B1" "B2" "B4" "B3" "B5" "A1" "A2" "A4" "A3" "A5"
```