# Create a combination of factors with optimization

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, combinatorics

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(
  First = c("MW3", "MW3", "MW4", "MW5", "MW6", "MW7", "MW7", "MW8"),
  Second = c("MW4; MW5; MW6", "MW5; MW3; MW7", "MW8; MW7; MW3",
             "MW5; MW6; MW4", "MW3; MW7; MW8", "MW6; MW8; MW4",
             "MW3; MW4; MW5", "MW6; MW3; MW7")
)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(
    ID = row_number(),
    lmt = n_distinct(ID)
  ) %>%
  separate_rows(Second, sep = "; ") %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(
    wgt = row_number()
  ) %>% ungroup()
```

Let's say that for each ID I want to keep only 1 combination of `First` and `Second` (i.e. the length of unique IDs in `df` should always be equal to `lmt`).

However, I'd like to do that with optimizing certain parameters. The solution should be designed in such a way that:

- Combinations with `wgt` 1 should be selected whenever possible, alternatively also 2, but 3 should be avoided (i.e. sum of `wgt` should be minimal);
- The difference between the frequency of a value in `Second` and frequency in `First` should be close to 0.

Any ideas on how to approach this in R?

Expected output for the above case is:

```
     ID First Second   wgt   lmt
1     1   MW3    MW4     1     8
2     2   MW3    MW7     3     8
3     3   MW4    MW7     2     8
4     4   MW5    MW5     1     8
5     5   MW6    MW3     1     8
6     6   MW7    MW8     2     8
7     7   MW7    MW3     1     8
8     8   MW8    MW6     1     8
```

Why? Simply because with this combination, there is not more of any element on the right side (`Second`) that it is on the left (`First`). For example, there are two MW3 elements on the right as well as on the left.

However, the price to pay here is that `wgt` is not always 1 (sum of `wgt` is not 8 but 12).

Clarification: In case both criteria cannot be minimized at the same time, the minimization of 2nd criteria (difference between frequencies) should be prioritized.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear as is. Is the desired output the last df snippet? Also, if `lmt` is always the same, what is point of it?

Comment: It's always the same because it is a constraint - I've just added it for emphasizing what kind of a constraint I'd like to have. Basically, this is the same as saying that the number of unique IDs in the final output has to be the same as in the initial input. As for the dataframe displayed, it is not the final output - unfortunately I don't have time to go through it at the moment, will add when I have it. But my question was more for some directions, and not for the final answer.

Comment: @Psych91: Could you please post the desired output? I do not understand your current requirements, especially the last one.

Comment: I've added the desired output.

Comment: The problem is that you give *two* criteria to guide the selection. A multi-objective optimization is ill-posed if you don't specify what to do when the two criteria pull in opposite directions. It would help if you would formulate this as a problem with a clear objective function and clear constraints.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can be more clear: sum of wgt parameter should be as low as possible AND difference between frequencies in Second and frequencies in First should be as low as possible or 0 AND the length of final dataset should always be equal to length of unique ID values (i.e. only 1 combination should be picked for each ID).

Comment: The problem is that you haven't said what to do if the choice that minimizes the sum of the `wgt` parameter *doesn't* at the same time minimize the the difference between the frequencies. In general, the objectives in a multi-objective minimization problem can clash (e.g. minimizing cost and minimizing fat might be incompatible objectives in a diet problem). This question seems somewhat ill-posed.

Comment: There are various ways that you can clarify this. For example, perhaps the second criteria could function as a tie-breaker for the first.

Comment: I see what you mean @JohnColeman - indeed, let's say the objective should be to prioritize the minimization of 2nd criteria (difference between frequencies).

Comment: The code to reproduce your data doesn't quite work. Some rows have `"MW5"` and others have `" MW5"` (note the space). Left alone, that will effect the frequency counts. Perhaps you want `separate_rows(Second, sep = "; ")` rather than `separate_rows(Second, sep = ";")`

Comment: You're right, corrected.

Comment: how large are the real data you will be using for this? If the data are not large, a brute-force solution would be easy enough (i.e. generate all the valid combinations then select the best from these). But this will not scale well, so only works for smallish data. e.g. your example has 3^8 combinations, which would be quite manageable.

Comment: Indeed, my above output was generated by a brute-force approach - but this is not what I'm looking for (which is why I put a bounty on it). The length of unique IDs could well be 200 or 300 ... so the solution should scale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I played around with this problem and I can share a solution using a variation of *minconflicts* algorithm. The key here is to find a scoring function that combines your requirements. The implementation below follows your recommendation '*let's say the objective should be to prioritize the minimization of 2nd criteria (difference between frequencies)*'. Experiment with other scoring functions on your actual data and let's see how far you get.

On your original data (8 IDs) I got solution equally good as the one you posted:

```
> solution_summary(current_solution)
   Name FirstCount SecondCount diff
1:  MW3          2           2    0
2:  MW4          1           1    0
3:  MW5          1           1    0
4:  MW6          1           1    0
5:  MW7          2           2    0
6:  MW8          1           1    0
[1] "Total freq diff:  0"
[1] "Total wgt:  12"
```

With random data with 10000 IDs the algorithm is able to find solution with no difference in First/Second frequencies (but sum of wgt is bigger than minimum):

```
> solution_summary(current_solution)
   Name FirstCount SecondCount diff
1:  MW3       1660        1660    0
2:  MW4       1762        1762    0
3:  MW5       1599        1599    0
4:  MW6       1664        1664    0
5:  MW7       1646        1646    0
6:  MW8       1669        1669    0
[1] "Total freq diff:  0"
[1] "Total wgt:  19521"
```

Code below:

```
library(data.table)
df <- as.data.table(df)
df <- df[, .(ID, First, Second, wgt)]

# PLAY AROUND WITH THIS PARAMETER
freq_weight <- 0.9

wgt_min <- df[, uniqueN(ID)]
wgt_max <- df[, uniqueN(ID) * 3]

freq_min <- 0
freq_max <- df[, uniqueN(ID) * 2] #verify if this is the worst case scenario

score <- function(solution){
  # compute raw scores
  current_wgt <- solution[, sum(wgt)]
  second_freq <- solution[, .(SecondCount = .N), by = Second]
  names(second_freq)[1] <- "Name"
  compare <- merge(First_freq, second_freq, by = "Name", all = TRUE)
  compare[is.na(compare)] <- 0
  compare[, diff := abs(FirstCount - SecondCount)]
  current_freq <- compare[, sum(diff)]

  # normalize
  wgt_score <- (current_wgt - wgt_min) / (wgt_max - wgt_min)
  freq_score <- (current_freq - freq_min) / (freq_max - freq_min)

  #combine
  score <- (freq_weight * freq_score) + ((1 - freq_weight) * wgt_score)
  return(score)
}

#initialize random solution
current_solution <- df[, .SD[sample(.N, 1)], by = ID]

#get freq of First (this does not change)
First_freq <- current_solution[, .(FirstCount = .N), by = First]
names(First_freq)[1] <- "Name"

#get mincoflict to be applied on each iteration
minconflict <- function(df, solution){
  #pick ID
  change <- solution[, sample(unique(ID), 1)]

  #get permissible values
  values <- df[ID == change, .(Second, wgt)]

  #assign scores
  values[, score := NA_real_]
  for (i in 1:nrow(values)) {
    solution[ID == change, c("Second", "wgt") := values[i, .(Second, wgt)]]
    set(values, i, "score", score(solution))
  }

  #return the best combination
  scores <<- c(scores, values[, min(score)])
  solution[ID == change, c("Second", "wgt") := values[which.min(score), .(Second, wgt)]]
}

#optimize
scores <- 1
iter <- 0
while(TRUE){
  minconflict(df, current_solution)
  iter <- iter + 1
  #SET MAX NUMBER OF ITERATIONS HERE
  if(scores[length(scores)] == 0 | iter >= 1000) break
}

# summarize obtained solution
solution_summary <- function(solution){
  second_freq <- solution[, .(SecondCount = .N), by = Second]
  names(second_freq)[1] <- "Name"
  compare <- merge(First_freq, second_freq, by = "Name", all = TRUE)
  compare[is.na(compare)] <- 0
  compare[, diff := abs(FirstCount - SecondCount)]
  print(compare)
  print(paste("Total freq diff: ", compare[, sum(diff)]))
  print(paste("Total wgt: ", solution[, sum(wgt)]))
}
solution_summary(current_solution)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a bipartite graph matching problem and so can be solved exactly in reasonable time, either by maxflow or linear programming ([bipartite graph matching to match two sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426295/bipartite-graph-matching-to-match-two-sets)).

```
library(lpSolve)
MISMATCH.COST <- 1000

.create.row <- function(row.names, first) {
    row <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length(first))
    for (i in 1:length(row.names))
        row = row + (-MISMATCH.COST+i)*(row.names[i]==first)
    return(row)
}

find.pairing <- function(First, Second) {
    row.names = sapply(Second, strsplit, "; ")

    # Create cost matrix for assignment
    mat = sapply(row.names, .create.row, First)
    assignment <- lp.assign(mat)
    print("Total cost:")
    print(assignment$objval+length(First)*MISMATCH.COST)
    solution <- lp.assign(mat)$solution
    pairs <- which(solution>0, arr.ind=T)
    matches = First[pairs[,1]]

    # Find out where a mismatch has occured, and replace match
    for (i in 1:length(matches)) {
        if (!(matches[i] %in% row.names[[i]])) {
            matches[i] = row.names[[i]][1]
        }
    }
    result = data.frame(
        First[pairs[,2]],
        matches)
    return(result)
}
```

Running it on your example gives an optimal solution (as it should always do)

```
> First = c("MW3", "MW3", "MW4", "MW5", "MW6", "MW7", "MW7", "MW8")
> Second = c("MW4; MW5; MW6", "MW5; MW3; MW7", "MW8; MW7; MW3",
           "MW5; MW6; MW4", "MW3; MW7; MW8", "MW6; MW8; MW4",
           "MW3; MW4; MW5", "MW6; MW3; MW7")
Second = c("MW4; MW5; MW6", "MW5; MW3; MW7", "MW8; MW7; MW3",
+            "MW5; MW6; MW4", "MW3; MW7; MW8", "MW6; MW8; MW4",
+            "MW3; MW4; MW5", "MW6; MW3; MW7")
> find.pairing(First, Second)
[1] "Total cost:"
[1] 12
  First.pairs...2.. matches
1               MW3     MW4
2               MW3     MW3
3               MW4     MW7
4               MW5     MW5
5               MW6     MW7
6               MW7     MW8
7               MW7     MW3
8               MW8     MW6
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - very interesting approach, so far so good. It's a pity I cannot at least split a bounty after it's been already awarded..